# How to upload multiple files separately in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Here is the problem I have. I need to create a web app capable of uploading two files of separate types (wav files and midi/MusicXML files respectively). Right now this does not work.
Here is my code:

`app.py`

```
flask import Flask

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Users/CatLover/Documents/DataScience/Insight/FrontEnd/Kitty/files/'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

`main.py`
    import os
    #import magic
    import urllib.request
    from app import app
    from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                print(request.__dict__)
        # check if the post request has the file part
                if 'file' not in request.files:
                        flash('No file part')
                        return redirect(request.url)
                file = request.files['file']
                if file.filename == '':
                        flash('No file selected for uploading')
                        return redirect(request.url)
                if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                        flash('File successfully uploaded')
                        return redirect('/')
                else:
                        flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
                        return redirect(request.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="127.0.0.1",port=int("5003"),debug=True)
```

`templates/upload.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask File Upload Example</title>
<h2>Step 1: Select a sheet music file (.xml, .mxl or .mid) to upload</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
<form method="post" name="sform" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="sfile" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="ssubmit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
<h2>Step 2: Select a wav file to upload</h2>
<form method="post" name="wform" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="wfile" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="wsubmit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure that use same input field names(mentioned in upload.html) in main.py
Here is the working solution , which will takes only 'xml', 'mxl','mid','wav' extensions, 
we can remove multiple upload field if we want, but as per your requirement I modified.
Thanks

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/root/Flask'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

main.py

```
import os
import magic
from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['xml', 'mxl','mid','wav'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                print(request.__dict__)
        # check if the post request has the file part
                if 'sfile' not in request.files:
                        flash('No file part')
                        return redirect(request.url)
                file = request.files['sfile']
                if file.filename == '':
                        flash('No file selected for uploading')
                        return redirect(request.url)
                if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                        flash('File successfully uploaded')
                        return redirect('/')
                else:
                        flash('Allowed file types are xml,mxl,mid,wav')
                        return redirect(request.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=int("5003"),debug=True)
```

templates/upload.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask File Upload Example</title>
<h2>Step 1: Select a sheet music file (.xml, .mxl or .mid) to upload</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
<form method="post" name="sform" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="sfile" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="ssubmit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
<h2>Step 2: Select a wav file to upload</h2>
<form method="post" name="wform" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="sfile" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="wsubmit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Happy to help ...!